# How can I copy a file and create the target directories at the same time?

Tags: directory, file-copy

I want to `cp aaa/deep/sea/blob.psd` to `bbb/deep/sea/blob.psd`

How do I do the copy if the `deep` and `sea` directories don't exist under `bbb` so that the copy both creates the directories that are needed and copies the file?

Right now I get
`No such file or directory` as deep and sea don't exist.

I looked thru the man help pages and other questions but nothing jumps out at me.

The closest I've got is using `rcp` for the directory:

```
rcp -r aaa/deep/sea/ bbb/deep/sea/
```

though this copies the whole directory and contents and I just want the one file.  Trying to do that however gave `cp: cannot create regular file bbb/deep/sea/blob.psd' such file or directory`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to use such next function for such situation:

```
copy_wdir() { mkdir -p -- "$(dirname -- "$2")" && cp -- "$1" "$2" ; }
```

and use it as

```
copy_wdir aaa/deep/sea/blob.psd bbb/deep/sea/blob.psd
```

By the way, GNU `cp` has a `--parents` option. It's really close to what you want, but not exactly. 
It will also create `aaa` directory that seems you don't need. However you can first cd to `aaa` and copy like:

```
cd aaa && cp --parents deep/sea/blob.psd ../bbb/
```

Answer (score 24):

It's easy using the `install` program from the *coreutils* that is typically used for this very purpose by build systems like *automake*:

```
install -D /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Note that `install` creates *all* parts of the path just like `mkdir -p` does, see `man install`. I'm curious why you didn't include *why* you want to do that. Calling `mkdir` and `cp` is very easy.

Comment: I think there are a lot of good answers on this question, but this one gets my vote as it's the most portable. The `rsync` answer will only create 1 directory, and `pax` doesn't seem to be common.

Comment: Use `-d` instead of `-D` on a Mac.

Comment: note that this command creates the destination files with `755` (`rwxr-xr-x`) permissions, which is probably not desired. you can specify something else with the `-m` switch, but I could not find a way to just _keep_ the file permissions :(

Answer (score 6):

With standard (POSIX/Unix) commands, you've got:

```
pax -rws ':^:dest/dir/:' file .
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd never heard of pax before. Though I like its concept. Unfortunately even though it's in POSIX, it seems very few distros install it by default :-(

Comment: @Patrick - if you skip all the way to the end of `info tar` - somewhere around the *portability concerns* section - i think youll find that GNU `tar` claims to be fully `pax` compatible. I did anyway, though i have never yet got around to putting those claims to a test.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of a way of doing it using `cp`, but it's certainly possible using `rsync`:

```
$ rsync sourcefile dir/
```

where `dir` is a directory that does not have to exist. There are lots of other ways of achieving the same using other commands.

Comment: You need `rsync -R` to preserve the directory heirarchy

Comment: @glennjackman Indeed, 'proper' use of `rsync` needs more options, but the question was simply about creating a non-existent target directory, hence my brief answer :)

Comment: At least the GNU `cp` has the `--parents` option.

Comment: @peterph Indeed, but then you're restricted in the naming of the target directory

Answer (score 4):

```
cd aaa
pax -rw deep/sea/blob.psd ../bbb
```

If you don't have `pax` (it's mandated by POSIX, as a standard replacement of cpio and tar which had too many incompatibilities to standardize), use `cpio -p` or `tar -cf - … | tar -xf -` instead.