# Copy multiple files and create the target directories at the same time?

Tags: bash, cp

I read [How can I copy a file and create the target directories at the same time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41770/how-can-i-copy-a-file-and-create-the-target-directories-at-the-same-time)

But the solution there only works if you want to copy **one** file.

How would I copy multiple files into a directory, that doesn't exist yet and auto-create it with one command?

for example:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir a/
cd a/
touch x1 x2
cp --magic * ../b/c/d/
```

so in the end the two files `x1` and `x2` are ordered like this:

```
/tmp/b/c/d/x1
/tmp/b/c/d/x2
```

Comment: Most of the solutions in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41770/how-can-i-copy-a-file-and-create-the-target-directories-at-the-same-time work for any number of files. Don't stop reading at the accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$ copy() { mkdir -p -- "${@: -1}" && cp -- "$@" ; }
$ copy * ../b/c/d/
```

Note: it works with bash, ksh93 and zsh.

`"${@: -1}"` corresponds to the `${parameter:offset}` form: all parameters starting at the offset. The offset -1 corresponds to the last parameter, since negative offsets count from the end. The space is necessary, otherwise it would be the `${parameter:-word}` form. See the bash manual for more information.

`"$@"` expands to the list of parameters, which is what is wanted for `cp`.

Note 2: As suggested by mikeserv, you can use

```
eval 'mkdir -p -- "${'"$#"'}"'
```

which is more portable (POSIX), instead of

```
mkdir -p -- "${@: -1}"
```

Concerning the performance, the `eval` solution is much faster with bash 4.3.30, but the other solution is faster with ksh 93u+ and zsh 5.0.6 (ksh93 and zsh being much faster than bash in both cases); and dash 5.7 with the `eval` solution (the other one is not supported) is a bit faster than ksh93 with the `"${@: -1}"` solution. So, depending on your case (script, interactive use, support for specific shell features, etc.), make your choice... Note however that in the context of `cp` (which will take most of the time), these performance differences won't be noticeable.

The script I used for the test:

```
i=50000
while [ $i -ne 0 ];
do
  # : "${@: -1}"
  eval ': "${'"$#"'}"'
  i=$((i-1))
done
```

(comment out the `eval` line and uncomment the previous line for the other solution), called with:

```
time sh ./tst `seq 1000`
time bash ./tst `seq 1000`
time ksh93 ./tst `seq 1000`
time zsh ./tst `seq 1000`
```

Comment: It could be more variable like `cp` if you would like to use this command as a complete ceplacement for `cp`: for example, if you copy only one file and the target does not end with a slash, then it should copy and rename the file to the target instead of creating a folder with the target name

Comment: You can do roughly the same thing POSIXLY like `eval 'mkdir -p -- "${'"$#"'}"' && cp -- "$@"`. Doing it that way also saves the shell from having to negatively index - and likely therefore iterate entirely through - the positional array which can be be computationally costly.

Comment: Thinking twice, it is probably worth testing for at least one arg though, like - `..."${'"$(($#?$#:1))"'}"...` which would save accidental creation of directories named `$0` - which your solution will not do.

Comment: @mikeserv If one wants to detect errors on the number of parameters, it's probably better to do it the usual way (`if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then ...`) and output an error message and return with a non-zero exit status. I think that anyone knows how to do this. There are various other ways to modify the command, e.g. to support the usual options, but this is getting more complex.

Comment: That does a non-zero exit status in the event the function is called without arguments - its return comes from `mkdir -p -- "$1"`. I dont know why you'd put a shell parser reserved word-type complex command like `if` on a single line like that. Another way might be `fn() { ${2+:} return 1;...}` or as a simpler means of doing the same the math expression does above: `...${2+"${'"$#"'}"}...`

Comment: @mikeserv The main point was a clear error message, hence the `if`. Something like: `if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then echo "Usage: $0 <file1> <file2> ... <directory>" >&2; return 1; fi`

Comment: `if` remains weird in that case. You need only do `fn() { eval ... && cp ... || ! echo error; } >&2`, else, far more readably you would use `if` but not as an afterthought - you should use it as the construct for the function like `fn() if eval ...\nthen cp ...\nelse ! echo...\nfi >&2`

Comment: @mikeserv Using `if [ $# -lt 2 ]; ...` avoids a double error message. Anyway I let the reader choose to handle error conditions the way he likes (there are plenty of ways to do); that's why I didn't do it in my answer.

Comment: `mkdir -p` prints no error, i think. Where would the second come from? In any case, the original point was that with `eval` and `$#` you can have both more portable and more performant code than you have now.

Comment: @mikeserv `mkdir -p` from coreutils prints errors in case of incorrect usage or when the directory cannot be created (Permission denied). The use of `eval` and `$#` makes the code more portable, but not more performant (there's no reason why the shell would loop for index -1: if the size is unknown, it would loop for `$#` too!); and it's less readable (users complain for even simpler code).

Comment: No - it shouldnt loop for `$#` because it is a special parameter that must always be set - but whether it does for the negative index depends on the shell. If `mkdir -p` is already printing an error message then why bother w/ an `echo`. I disagree about the readability thing - you even mention in your answer that your -1 must be spaced because even the shell might misunderstand it - but that is a matter of preference. At the very least making the function portable enables it to be run on faster shells than you target which proves the performance there, but probably faster all told anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv `$#` is always set, but this doesn't say whether it is computed dynamically by the shell or not (the user won't see the difference, possibly except by timings). Concerning the performance, I've edited my answer, but as you can see, the best choice completely depends on the shell. And if the user cares about performance, he shouldn't use bash anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and used `tar` to solve it! Like so:

```
tmpfile=/tmp/myfile.tar
files="/some/folder/file1.txt /some/other/folder/file2.txt"
targetfolder=/home/you/somefolder

tar --file="$tmpfile" "$files"​
tar --extract --file="$tmpfile" --directory="$targetfolder"
```

In this case, `tar` will automatically create all (sub)folders for you! Best,

Nabi