# Make parent directories while creating a new file

Tags: shell, command-line, mkdir

I am aware of the fact that `mkdir -p /path/to/new/directory` will create a new directory, along with parent directory (if needed ).

If I have to create a new file, along with it's parent directories (where some or all of the parent directories are not present), I could use `mkdir -p /path/to/directory && touch /path/to/directory/NEWFILE`. But, is there any other command to achieve this?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41770/4358

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, there is nothing standard like that, but you can do it your self:

```
ptouch() {
  for p do
    _dir="$(dirname -- "$p")"
    mkdir -p -- "$_dir" &&
      touch -- "$p"
  done
}
```

Then you can do:

```
ptouch /path/to/directory/file1 /path/to/directory/fil2 ...
```

Comment: what is dirname on line 3 ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html

Comment: how is `p` being defined in `for p do`.  I would have thought you'd need to use `$@` here...

Comment: @Jonah `for p do` is short form of `for p in "$@"; do`

Answer (score 4):

Some systems have a `install` command that can be told to create missing path components.

With the GNU implementation of `install`,

```
install -DTm644 /dev/null foo/bar/baz
```

Would create an empty `baz` regular file with permission 0644 and would create the `foo` and `foo/bar` directories if missing (with permission 0755 regardless of the umask).

Comment: Or with curl ... curl --create-dirs --output /tmp/create/file.txt file:///dev/null

Comment: It's admittedly been many, many years, but I'm almost certain that that's possible in other implementations of *`install`* too (I'm not sure that *`/dev/null`* is a good thing to include in your example though ...).

Comment: @Pryftan, I didn't mean to imply that it wasn't possible with other `install` implementations, just that that's the syntax to use for GNU `install` and how it does it. The syntax would be different for FreeBSD `install` (you'd at least need `-d` in place of `-D` and I don't think it's got an equivalent for `-T`, though that's only a safeguard option). You need a source file. `/dev/null` is used to create an empty `foo/bar/baz`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right. As I noted it had been years :) As for the source file: well to be fair I wasn't truly paying attention to it other than - well you probably know where my mind was maybe even more than me! With your explanation I can see indeed what you're doing; I wasn't even thinking of files actually so that could be part of the problem too. Anyway yes - *`install`* is a great option here.